# Why can't Vim open a 100 MB text file when I have 16 GB RAM?

Tags: vim, memory

I have a 100MB MySQL database backup file and I have trouble to open it in Vim on my Linux box that has 16G of RAM.

Vim just hangs (at least unusable). This is something I don't understand. I have 16 GB RAM, why can't I load a 100 MB file in an editor?

Is it because of Vim? I thought all the memory management is handled by the OS.

Comment: Consider using a HEX editor instead of a text editor to view such files. An example of hex editor with vi-like interface would be `hexer`.

Comment: Don't forget that **RAM has not been what we run out of when we run out of memory** for decades now.  Memory is now virtualized; it is divided up into pages and those pages can be swapped to disk. The amount of memory allocated out of a process's address space and the amount of RAM consumed have very little to do with each other. When you run out of memory, you've run out of *address space*, not *RAM*. The best way to think of it is *memory is disk space*, each process gets a certain fixed amount of that space, and *RAM is hardware that makes your disk faster*.

Comment: @EricLippert Except that traditional disks are so slow (compared to RAM) that they are only suitable for storing the virtual memory pages that are not in active use.  **If a process hangs (or is at least unusable, as the OP put it) due to swap thrashing, it is precisely because RAM is what it has run out of.**

Comment: @EricLippert running out of address space is only relevant on 32 bit systems today. I doubt that the user with 16G RAM will still use 32 bit PAE kernel instead of normal 64 bit one.

Comment: @depquid: That is a good point; the thrust of my comment is that the OP seems to have the belief that "I loaded 100MB of stuff, I have 16000MB of RAM, so therefore 100MB of my 16000MB of RAM was consumed".  This belief system is outdated.

Comment: @Ruslan: That is also a good point. See my previous comment.

Comment: You might want to give [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) a try.

Comment: It's probably trying to syntax highlight the file, or otherwise parse it. Hit control-c to interupt it.

Comment: Vim is for text, I would use `head` or `tail` to view binary file

Comment: Have you turned off syntax highlighting? What plugins do you have running? Try it with `vim -u NONE --noplugin`

Comment: Also editing a 100MB file in vim or any text editor seems like a bad idea. I'd look into using ex  or `vim -e` instead.

Comment: Do you running many other applications when trying edit your 100M file with vim? What does top/htop say? I've been edited a 1.2G file (nginx access log) on a linux box with only 4G RAM without any issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and suggestions and I believe it is the extra long lines that caused me the problems, I created a 500MB file without extra long lines and Vim handled it nicely.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Vim sometimes has trouble with files that have unusually long lines. It's a text editor, so it's designed for text files, with line lengths that are usually at most a few hundred characters wide.

A database file may not contain many newline characters, so it could conceivably be one single 100 Mb long line. Vim will not be happy with that, and although it will probably work, it might take quite a long time to load the file.

I have certainly opened **text** files much larger than 100 Mb with Vim. The file doesn't even need to fit in memory all at once (since Vim can swap changes to disk as needed).

Comment: I also noticed the very long lines, tried with another file without very long lines, see a big improvement. Thanks

Comment: @AskandLearn Depending on the file type, you may see a performance increase if you `set synmaxcol=120` (or some other appropriate number).  I've noticed huge speedups from this in the past.

Comment: Does anyone know if the recent neovim fork will handle longer lines better? I guess it isn't a particularly common issue...

Comment: @GregHewgill it's true, I've also observe that, but how did you know that ?

Answer (score 57):

In my experience Vim chokes not on **large files**, but on **long lines**. Use this command to have [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) use *shorter lines* at the expense of a *larger file*:

```
$ mysqldump --complete-insert -u -p
```

Additionally, you can open Vim and ask it not to parse your `.vimrc` file or load any plugins with this command:

```
$ vim -u NONE output.sql
```

Loading Vim in this manner will use less memory and not require Vim to parse the entire file as many plugins do.

Answer (score 15):

"load VIM without .vimrc and plugins (clean VIM) e.g. for HUGE files

```
  gvim -u NONE -U NONE -N largefile.sql
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using `less` instead of `vim` if you want to view a large file directly.  Vim tries to do a lot of different stuff when it first loads - scanning the file (potentially in multiple passes) to try to determine what syntax to use, and performing syntax highlighting, and searching for modelines at the top and bottom of the file.  Then as you edit the file, vim is saving swapfiles and keeping undo trees (undo history in vim is branching, not linear like in every (?) other editor), and constantly re-evaluating the syntax highlighting as the text changes, etc.

None of that is necessarily a justification for why it must be so unusable with giant files, but it's more of an explanation of some of the reasons why it is.

Comment: See my answer for how to prevent VIM from performing the heavy operations such as file parsing.

Comment: Yup, syntax highlighting on things like XML and SQL can get very slow on larger files.

Answer (score 10):

Vim does not just load the file as-is into memory. It converts it into internal structures (lines, words, etc), performs syntax highlighting using an internal script language, and so on; all of which consumes memory (a whole lot more than a byte for a character) and CPU time.

Comment: Consuming memory is not even the issue. CPU time being taken up (and a visible freeze whilst you wait), is.

Comment: That CPU time is mostly taken up by the syntax highlighting script.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm just saying that memory usage is very unlikely to (a) be a problem, or (b) cause a long delay, contrary to what your answer says.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

You may try loading it as a binary. I've had luck with that for really big, non-text files

```
vim -b HUGEFILE
```

It's also possible IIRC to use vim as a hex editor see: http://usevim.com/2012/06/20/vim-binary-files/

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully your problem is more to do with VIMs need for temporary files (such as swap) more than RAM.

In many cases, the temporary files created by VIM are in the same directory of the file you are opening. If this is the case for you, then you can verify by checking the available disk space in the current directory.

Fortunately, there is good documentation on how you can specify a different location for VIM's indexing/swap files:

- [Move vi/vim editor temporary swap and backup files to another directory](http://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/vi-vim-swap-backup-tilde-temporary-files-directory-move)
- [Remove swap and backup files from your working directory](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory)

You can also disable the swap file

- [Disabling swap files creation in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821902/disabling-swap-files-creation-in-vim)

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally open large database backups in .sql text format.   Very large files, or files with very long lines often  sometimes seem to take a long time to open in vim.   This might be related to syntax processing and colour highlighting, as mentioned in answers by @zzapper and @demonkoryu.

A quick workaround might be to press "control-G" during loading of the file to cancel the syntax highlighting pre-processing.